# Comments not working in jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a template(test.html) as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="/create_user/" method="post">
                {{ form.csrf_token }}
                <dl>
                    {{ render_field(form.name) }}
                    {{ render_field(form.members) }}
                    <!--<div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            {{ form.task.label }}
                        </label>
                        <div class='controls'>
                            {{ form.task}}

                            {% if form.task.errors %}
                            <ul class="text-error">
                                {% for error in form.task.errors %}
                                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>-->
                </dl>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

When rendering this template using Flask's render_template("test.html", form=form). I got following error "UndefinedError: 'tickapp.forms.TeamForm object' has no attribute 'task'".
As you can see I have commented out 'form.task' in the template(whole ) and also there is no such field in models and in my form.

I wonder why jinja2 is considering commented html content. I trusted comments(!) and spent couple of hours on this issue. Finally, deleted all the comments and it started working.Anybody working in jinja2 faced this problem? and do you know why it is happening?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Basically, jinja2 is only concerned with finding an evaluating its own blocks, not the structure of the HTML.  If you want to exclude a section of your template entirely, you can use jinja2's [comment syntax](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#comments):

```
{# This is a comment now.
    <div class="control-group">
       ...
    </div>
#}
```

Comment: Thanks. I started using jinja2 comments. I didn't find any such problem in Django templates and I think jinja2 should allow html-style commenting instead of their own commenting style.

Comment: Dropping by a year later... I disagree, @rajpy.  I found this question while googling for a way to add comments to my jinja2 source without actually emitting those comments in the HTML (for security reasons).  You get the most flexibility if jinja2 only knows and deals with its own syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This came up as the top link on Google for "jinja comments not working" so I wanted to describe another caveat.

You can use `{#` to start a comment and `#}` to end a comment with jinja2, as mentioned [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16302254/5049813). However, *you cannot nest comments*.

That is, if you have:

```
    {# This does NOT comment out the whole block now.
        <div class="control-group">
           ...
           {# Inner comment that will stop the comment block here --> #}
           ...
        </div>
    #}
```

the comment ending symbol for the inner comment will end up ending the block prematurely.

So, if you have pure-text comments that just comment on what jinja is doing, you should use regular HTML comments like `<!-- Here's a text comment -->` to comment those so that you can still comment out blocks as needed.

This is what you might expect from block comments, but it still tripped me up the first time I saw it, so I figured I would mention it.