# flask render_template giving error for commented html code

Tags: flask, jinja2

It's weird that `flask`'s `render_template` was throwing an exception which was generated because of my commented code in html.
below is the html comment I made

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to XYZ</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <p>{{ result }}</p>
            <p> {{ direct_url_for_login }}</p>
            <p> {{ _company }}</p>

            {% for key, value in result.items() %}
            <p>{{ key }}</p>
            <p>{{ value }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html> -->
```

I am just curious If there is something I am doing wrong , or it's an expected behaviour. because I was getting `result is undefined` exception thrown, where i kept the render_template part.
Thanks in Advance.

```
try:
    ...
    ...
    return render_template('foo.html',**locals()), 200
except Exception as e:
    return jsonify({'message':str(e)}), 500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's normal ... you are trying to render an empty page.

Why do you put in comment all your page ?

Maybe you could have your answer there : [Comments not working in jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275877/comments-not-working-in-jinja2)

or there : http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#comments

Comment: Thanks @Phx Dev, I got the answer from the link you provided, but the html page is not empy I have html code on top of that ,I posted only the commented code.

Comment: So : http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#comments